# Is it possible to generate conditions such that the temperature difference created by current is high enough to sustain it?

Tags: electricity, temperature, electric-current, perpetual-motion, thermoelectricity

We know that current can generate temperature difference and vice-versa.

But is it possible to generate such conditions that the temperature difference created by current is high enough to sustain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is a little unclear what you mean here, I will respond with some thoughts.

If what you ask were true (that the temperature difference could create a self-sustaining current flow) then you'd have a perpetual motion machine. Any time this possibility pops up in an analysis, it's an indication that there's an error in your reasoning, and you have to go back and identify it- rather than asserting your right to a Nobel prize, as many others do in similar circumstances.